# I have two drop down lists with the same data of city's

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
list1            list2

pune              pune
mumbai           mumbai  
lonavala        lonavala
```

If I select `pune` in the first list, in the secound list `pune` will be hidden. I'm using codeignitor; it is dynamic drop down list.

[image]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with SQL/MySQL, and AJAX. I have removed those tags

Answer (score 1):

*You may use 
`$("#list2").val(...);`
and
`$("#list2").find("option:selected").remove();`
together as :*

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list1').on('change',function(){
        var v_selected = $(this).val();
            $("#list2").val(v_selected);
        if  ( v_selected == 'List1_0') 
             $("#list2").val('List2_0');
        else $("#list2").find("option:selected").remove();
    });
});
</script>
<label for="list1"> List1 </label>
<select id="list1">
<option value="List1_0" selected >Please Select ... </option> 
<option value="Pune" >Pune</option> 
<option value="Mumbai" >Mumbai</option> 
<option value="Lonavala" >Lonavala</option> 
</select>
<br>
<label for="list2"> List2 </label>
<select id="list2">
<option value="List2_0" selected >Please Select ... </option> 
<option value="Pune" >Pune</option> 
<option value="Mumbai" >Mumbai</option> 
<option value="Lonavala" >Lonavala</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: i am not working only for "pune" city. if i selected any city in 1st list then that city name will be remove from second list.

Comment: @ShaikhFarhanSultan ok I edited to include all cases for the cities' selection. Please edit your question with this desired information also.